# Different language keyboard for single activity in Android

Tags: android, input, keyboard

Excuse me if the explanation is a little vague, but I have looked around for awhile and have not found a definitive solution to this issue.

**The application is in English, but there is one Activity/EditText that needs to accept Thai input, thus I need the Thai keyboard to show for this Edittext.**

I can create my own fully custom keyboard (Google Soft Keyboard Example), but the time it would take for that I want to avoid.

I can ask the user to download extra language packs/keyboards, but is there a way to set the locale of just one Activity/EditText?

Thanks guys, any help is appreciated